# Tensorflow pseudo inverse doesn't work for complex matrices

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matrix, matrix-inverse

The [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/pinv) says that:

> tf.linalg.pinv is "analogous to numpy.linalg.pinv. It differs only in default value of rcond".

However, `tf.linalg.pinv` requires the matrix to be float type while `np.linalg.pinv` could be used with complex matrices.

I was wondering why they would only create it for float types and if there is a straightforward way to modify `tf.linalg.pinv` to be used with complex matrices

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same situation. If you need to explicitly build the inverse, check this paper:

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f278/b548b5121fd0d09c2e589439b97fad16ece3.pdf

In particular, given a Matrix M that you need to invert, you can just do:

```
    A = tf.math.real(M)
    C = tf.math.imag(M)

    r0  = tf.linalg.pinv(A) @ C
    y11 = tf.linalg.pinv(C @ r0 + A)
    y10 = -r0 @ y11

    M_inverse = tf.cast(tf.complex(y11,y10), dtype = M.dtype)
```

The complexity is a bit higher than the pure-complex implementation, but so far it has proven to be pretty stable for me.